# Can Image or any other document(pdf/word/text) upload as a same time?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to upload image & other document like PDF/doc/text etc in one form but at one time i am able to upload only one thing, can i upload the same in one form using codeIgniter ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... We can upload different format at the same time with the help of codeigniter functions.

first initialize one configuration for one format like:

```
$config['upload_path'] = $upload_path;
$config['file_name'] = rand(10,99);
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);               //initialize upload config

$this->upload->do_upload($filename)
```

when upload one format file then reset the configuration

```
unset($config);
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

after that you can initialize another configuration for another format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single form, but you controller's logic has to be different to accept multiple files

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config); //initial load of the upload library
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name1); //uploading first file
[...]
$this->upload->initialize($config); //re-initializing the config
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name2); //uploading second file
```

If you have more files to upload, you may wanna put your logic in a loop.

Comment: in controller i am using one function to submit both of them but not succeed yet.